# How to upload a new version to google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

Today my app was just has been review in the Google Play store, it takes 4 days to publish. But now I want to upload a new version of my app, how can I do that? I have changed my version code to a greater number, and build an .aab file. But I do not know where I can upload this new version. Hope help from everyone, thanks so much! <3

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to Google Play console
2. click on your app
3. left menu, find production & click on it.
4. now on right window search for relase
5. create new release, upload signed apk, fill up the information
6. safe and rollout. That's it.

For more help please consider this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGoCF0Et_CU